# SharePoint 2013 - A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-collection, site-template

I am getting this error while creating SharePoint site with a specific site template **GLOBAL#0** and **SRCHCENTERFAST#0**. 
*I am able to create site with other templates.*

> A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site.  Please choose another title

```
New-SPSite -Url "http://sptest.domain.com" -HostHeaderWebApplication "http://spserver:8000/" -Language 1033 -Template "GLOBAL#0" -Name "Data Site" -Description "Data Site" -OwnerEmail "owner@email.com" -OwnerAlias "domain\user"
```

Comment: what happens when you go to central admin, create site collection, select 'select the template later' and then pick the template in the next step?

Comment: Can you please tell more.?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that the templates which are problematic are actually set to hidden. And these templates are not visible in SharePoint Central Administration site.

Some of these templates are for internal use (you can see their xml config file ). So in my opinion this may be one of the causes that these templates cannot be applied on SharePoint site.